# Connection controller with Scene Builider events

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

How I can get connection with the Keyboard / Mouse etc events using Scene Builder ??
My code looks like :

```
@FXML 
    public void onKeyPressed() {
          group.getScene().setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
              double change = 10.0;
              if(event.isShiftDown()) { change = 50.0; }
              KeyCode keycode = event.getCode();
              if(keycode == KeyCode.W) { perspectiveCamera.setTranslateZ(perspectiveCamera.getTranslateZ() + change); }
              if(keycode == KeyCode.S) { perspectiveCamera.setTranslateZ(perspectiveCamera.getTranslateZ() - change); }
              if(keycode == KeyCode.A) { perspectiveCamera.setTranslateX(perspectiveCamera.getTranslateX() - change); }
              if(keycode == KeyCode.D) { perspectiveCamera.setTranslateX(perspectiveCamera.getTranslateX() + change); }
          });    
    }
    @FXML
    public void onMousePressed() {
        group.getScene().setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent me) -> {
             mousePosX = me.getSceneX();
             mousePosY = me.getSceneY();
             mouseOldX = me.getSceneX();
             mouseOldY = me.getSceneY();
         });
    }
    @FXML
    public void onMouseDragged() {
        group.getScene().setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent me) -> {
            mouseOldX = mousePosX;
            mouseOldY = mousePosY;
            mousePosX = me.getSceneX();
            mousePosY = me.getSceneY();
            mouseDeltaX = (mousePosX - mouseOldX);
            mouseDeltaY = (mousePosY - mouseOldY);

            double modifier = 10.0;
            double modifierFactor = 0.1;

            if (me.isControlDown()) {
                modifier = 0.1;
            }
            if (me.isShiftDown()) {
                modifier = 50.0;
            }
            if (me.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                cameraTransformer.ry.setAngle(((cameraTransformer.ry.getAngle() + mouseDeltaX * modifierFactor * modifier * 2.0) % 360 + 540) % 360 - 180);  // +
                cameraTransformer.rx.setAngle(((cameraTransformer.rx.getAngle() - mouseDeltaY * modifierFactor * modifier * 2.0) % 360 + 540) % 360 - 180);  // -
            } else if (me.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                double z = perspectiveCamera.getTranslateZ();
                double newZ = z + mouseDeltaX * modifierFactor * modifier;
                perspectiveCamera.setTranslateZ(newZ);
            } else if (me.isMiddleButtonDown()) {
                cameraTransformer.t.setX(cameraTransformer.t.getX() + mouseDeltaX * modifierFactor * modifier * 0.3);  // -
                cameraTransformer.t.setY(cameraTransformer.t.getY() + mouseDeltaY * modifierFactor * modifier * 0.3);  // -
            }
        });
    }
```

And the Scene Builder panel : 
[image]

I usually do always in the same way and it works but now using this panel does not. Where I am doing mistake ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the mouse events, set them in the anchorpane:

```
<AnchorPane onMouseDragged="#onMouseDragged" onMousePressed="#onMousePressed" ...>
   <children>
      <Group fx:id="group" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and now in your controller pass the event directly:

```
@FXML
private void onMousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    mousePosX = me.getSceneX();
    mousePosY = me.getSceneY();
    mouseOldX = me.getSceneX();
    mouseOldY = me.getSceneY();
}

@FXML
private void onMouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
    mouseOldX = mousePosX;
    mouseOldY = mousePosY;
    mousePosX = me.getSceneX();
    mousePosY = me.getSceneY();
    ...
}
```

As for the key pressed event, it seems the scene takes this event and consumes it, so you need to propagate it from the scene to the controller:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Window3DSceneView.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    Window3DController controller = loader.getController();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 800, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
    scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> controller.onKeyPressed(e));
    ...
}
```

And now in your controller:

```
 public void onKeyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
      double change = 10.0;
      if(event.isShiftDown()) { change = 50.0; }
      KeyCode keycode = event.getCode();
      ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, its working now, also I saw u added 2 more arguments to the scene constructor " true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED " after adding this i got undesirable effect, did upload on my question, what caused this ?

Comment: Depth buffer is required when you have more objects for depth sorted rendering, for now you don't need it, so you can set it to false and see it the artifact disappear. As for the Antialiasing, it affects the smoothness of the rendered scene. Try also disabling it.

Comment: Dunno why but i got this problem while I'm pressing the mouse, what can be cause ? Did edit.

Comment: Post the line 87 of the controller

Comment: cameraTransformer.ry.setAngle(((cameraTransformer.ry.getAngle() + mouseDeltaX * modifierFactor * modifier * 2.0) % 360 + 540) % 360 - 180);  // + This line is in the onMouseDragged method, but it pop when evokes onMousePressed

Comment: Are you adding `cameraTransformer = window3dBuilder.getCameraTransformer();` in `initialize()`?